# Is this really the proper way to send data over BLE? (Using Adafruit example as reference)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, adafruit, nrf51

I have to send data over BLE as fast as possible with the Adafruit BLE SPI friend.  I have an idea of what GATT service I'd like to use. In the [heartratemonitor.ino](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BluefruitLE_nRF51/blob/master/examples/heartratemonitor/heartratemonitor.ino) BLE example from adafruit, I am confused about the way they send data.  It seems they just update the heart rate measurement characteristic with the AT+GATTCHAR= command. The update is then just read from their Bluefruit app. This method to send data seems to be painfully slow and not very efficient at all. I have looked through the [Adafruit BLE library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BluefruitLE_nRF51) for the BLE SPI friend and I cant seem to find another legit way to update/send data. Am I missing something in my understanding, or is this just not the best library to send data with?

note: I have to read data from a buffer with SPI and send it over bluetooth. Thought about just using a SPI library (ok difficulty) and any other nordic or nRF51822 library, but the learning curve seems VERY steep.

```
void loop(void)
{
  int heart_rate = random(50, 100);

  Serial.print(F("Updating HRM value to "));
  Serial.print(heart_rate);
  Serial.println(F(" BPM"));

  /* Command is sent when \n (\r) or println is called */
  /* AT+GATTCHAR=CharacteristicID,value */
  ble.print( F("AT+GATTCHAR=") );
  ble.print( hrmMeasureCharId );
  ble.print( F(",00-") );
  ble.println(heart_rate, HEX);

  /* Check if command executed OK */
  if ( !ble.waitForOK() )
  {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to get response!"));
  }

  /* Delay before next measurement update */
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is moving slower is because of the delay at the end of the loop.

```html
  /* Delay before next measurement update */
  delay(1000);
```

That's a way of asking the Bluefruit to wait one second (1000 milliseconds) before executing again.

Reducing that number should speed up the loop.